# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined in api direction service

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am receiving this error when I try to load an HTML page with my map:

Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

I thought it was the order in which I was loading the Google maps API, but I have it at the beginning.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<body>

  <section class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row input-user text-center">
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="input-lokasi">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start" placeholder="Lokasi">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="icon-lokasi-tujuan">
                <i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill fs-2"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="input-tujuan">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end" placeholder="Tujuan">
              </div>
            </div>

          <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-5">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
            </div>
          </div>
    
        </div>
        <div class="maps-box mt-4">
          <div class="map" id="map">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <!-- <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> -->
  <script src="maps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={}&libraries=places">
    </script>
</body>
```

my javascript code like this:

```
var map;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var harga = 1.7;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {
    lat: -7.960996,
    lng: 112.618634
  },
  zoom: 16
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var start = document.getElementById('start');
var searchStart = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(start);
var end = document.getElementById('end');
var searchEnd = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(end);

var detail = document.getElementById('detail');

var pesanStart = document.getElementById('pesan-btn');

function findRoute() {
  var startAddress = start.value;
  var endAddress = end.value;
  var request = {
    origin: startAddress,
    destination: endAddress,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
      console.log(result);
      console.log(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
      console.log(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);

      document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
      document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML = result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
      document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 'Rp' + result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value*harga;


      detail.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      detail.style.display = 'none';
      alert('Petunjuk arah gagal dimuat, masukkan alamat yang benar!');
    }
  });
}

pesan.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (start.value.trim() != "" && end.value.trim() != "") {
    event.preventDefault();
    findRoute();
  }
});
```

I hope someone can help me, thank you

Comment: Please edit out and avoid posting your API key on public sites, as this could lead to billing issues for you in the future. as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices

Comment: I tried reproducing your code, but I'm encountering error on the `pesan.addEventListener` below. You don't seem to have a variable called `pesan`. But I can see that you have `pesanStart` variable. Can you try checking that out?

Comment: yes i mean `pesanStart.addEventListener`

Comment: but my problem in `var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();`

Comment: I noticed that you also did not have an map initialization callback. You did not have the `initMap` that is similar on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DisplayingResults). Also your `<script>` tag did not have the callback like this: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are including the Google Maps API after the code that depends on it

```
<script src="maps.js"></script> <! -- script that depends on the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 -->
<!-- load of Google Maps JavaScript API -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={}&libraries=places"></script>
```

2. If I reverse those two lines, I get a different error (as @Yrll pointed out in the comments): `Uncaught ReferenceError: pesan is not defined`
3. If I fix that (by changing it to `pesanStart`) as indicated in the comments, I get a  third error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`, because there is no element with `id=pesan-btn` in the posted HTML.

If I fix that, I get a map with no errors, the autocomplete inputs work and the direction service works.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/21fmewn5/)

[image: screenshot of map with directions]

**code snippet:**

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="container" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
        <div class="col-md-8" style="height:100%;">
          <div class="row input-user text-center">
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="input-lokasi">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start" placeholder="Lokasi">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="icon-lokasi-tujuan">
                <i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill fs-2"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="input-tujuan">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end" placeholder="Tujuan">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row text-center">
              <div class="col-md-5">
              <button id="pesan-btn">
              start
              </button>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-2">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-5">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="maps-box mt-4" style="height:70%;">
            <div class="map" id="map">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var harga = 1.7;

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: -7.960996,
          lng: 112.618634
        },
        zoom: 16
      });
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

      var start = document.getElementById('start');
      var searchStart = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(start);
      var end = document.getElementById('end');
      var searchEnd = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(end);

      var detail = document.getElementById('detail');

      var pesanStart = document.getElementById('pesan-btn');

      function findRoute() {
        var startAddress = start.value;
        var endAddress = end.value;
        var request = {
          origin: startAddress,
          destination: endAddress,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
            console.log(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);

            document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
            document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML = result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
            document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 'Rp' + result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value * harga;


            detail.style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            detail.style.display = 'none';
            alert('Petunjuk arah gagal dimuat, masukkan alamat yang benar!');
          }
        });
      }

      pesanStart.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (start.value.trim() != "" && end.value.trim() != "") {
          event.preventDefault();
          findRoute();
        }
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```